# Redirection issues under subdomains

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have been doing a basic application, which may contain all the issues I have had recently.

I tried to map the endpoints specified in the code under "/example/", "/example/add" and "/example/add2", but unfortunately I got 404 when I tried to submit the form.

My code works if I don't use subdomains, jut map everthing under "/".

Here's my relevant code:

```
//@RequestMapping("/example") --> also tried to put it here
public class AttractionController {

private AttractionService attractionService;

@Autowired
public AttractionController(AttractionService attractionService) {
  this.attractionService = attractionService;
}

@RequestMapping("/example")
 @GetMapping("/")
  String main(Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("attractions", attractionService.findAll());
  return "main";
 }

 @PostMapping("/add")
  String add(@ModelAttribute Attraction attraction) {
   attractionService.save(attraction);
 return "redirect:/";
 }

 @PostMapping("/add2")
  String add2(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam Double latitude, 
  @RequestParam String city, Model model) {
   attractionService.save(new Attraction(name, latitude, city));
    return "redirect:/";
    //also tried to use return "redirect:/example"
 }
```

HTML:

```
<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{add}">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="latitude">
  <input type="text" name="city">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{add2}">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="latitude">
  <input type="text" name="city">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you have a `@RequestMapping("/example")` on the top of `@GetMapping("/")`?

Comment: I'm just trying to map every endpoint under "/example". Basically I put above the class, but it did not work like this, so I tried it this way as well.

Comment: Add `@RestController` above the class definition and below that the `@RequestMapping("/<as-you-need>")` and try once.